# Product backlog in ADO

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How do I define a story as being in the product backlog and will be pulled into future sprints? Currently I'm forced to assign such stories to some random future sprint which is cumbersome and later move to current sprint. how do I make a product backlog in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

you just have to select the root iteration

for instance, if your project is named "XXX", iteration will be XXX/sprint1, XXX/sprint2
but you just have to put "XXX" and it will not be assigned to any sprint.

default iteration is a configurable setting

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Bobbob601, you can set the [Default iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#select-team-sprints-and-set-the-default-iteration-path) in the Team Configuration of Project Settings, so that it can automatically assign iteration to newly created work items.

[image]

In addition, you can batch modify the `iteration path` of work items through query:

[image]

[image]